# How to create a shared React UI Component Library in a Monorepo system?

Tags: reactjs, monorepo, lerna

I am making an application which is divided into two parts, one is a user facing application that will be directly used by the end user lets call it **EndUserApp**.

Other is a admin / seller application which will be used by seller, admins and morderations, lets call this **SellerApp**.

These two applications have a lot of UI components in common and have same UI theme and design, so i create a third app, lets call it **EComUI**

All these apps are inside a monorep which is managed by lerna.
So now I need to import components from **EComUI** into **SellerApp** and **EndUserApp**.

There are two ways this can be achieved,

1. We can create **EComUI** as a compiled UI library, which uses a webpack-server(or anyother) to build components and add this lib as a dependency in both **SellerApp** and **EndUserApp** and then use it as a normal node package.
2. The other way is to import the components directly into **SellerApp** and **EndUserApp**, from workspace like `EComUI/Button`.

i have seen both implemented, both of these work, the 2nd  method has an advantage of not needing to create a build over and over again or have an additional dev-server running while coding.
While the 1st one has an advantage of being a complete package in itself, that can be moved or uploaded to NPM later on if required.

How should I implement a shared UI lib in a react monorepo? Is there any important drawback that any of the two proposed methods that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Have you looked into git submodules? Great way of sharing such things

Comment: Have you tried webpack module fedaration? which allows a JavaScript application to dynamically load code from another application

Comment: @RaghuRam not looking to use micro-frontend, will have to go with monorepo solution.

Comment: @Gandzal sub modules is a step above using a separate package and pushing it on npm

Answer (score 1):

## Why not both?

You can get the best of both worlds by making your library a workspace inside your monorepo. That means that you can effectively import your components directly in the application if needed, while also defining transpilation steps inside the package itself. This makes it easily publishable to npm as the workspace itself is a package.

By having a project structure similar to

```
/apps
  |_ /EndUserApp
       |_ package.json
  |_ /SellerApp
       |_ package.json
/packages
  |_ /EComUI
       |_ /lib
       |_ /src
       |_ package.json
```

You can have both the transpiled version of the library for publishing to npm as well as the sources.

With such a structure you can even choose whether to use library sources inside your apps and transpiling them via configuration specific to the project (minimizing bundle size by dropping backwards compatibility is a thing that comes to mind for newer projects) or the already transpiled version.